# Execution time for sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, iteration, imputation

I am using the  sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer with extra tree regressor and it is taking too much time, it's almost been an hour and it is still running. Is there a way I can check how much has been executed and estimated time left?

Answer (score 1):

I don't you can tell estimated time as a direct measure or so. But use `verbose=2` as a paramter to `sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer`. That will give you some idea about how what it is doing and every step. So You can estimate may be rough estimated time, if you have knowledge on algorithm.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Do you know if Joblib can help it process faster? and how to use it. Fairly new to all this.

Comment: Well `Joblib` can make faster if your algorithm supports parallelism. If you are talking about this `sklearn` methods, then You need to check if the particular algorithm supports `joblib` or not. For Example joblib is a better option to dump and load sklearn objects (ref. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).

Comment: Never tried on `sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer`. Need to check.

Here is the ref. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/performance.html . Just give a try. This is how you can use joblib.

Comment: To be frank, as far i know, joblib uses cache technique for efficient utilisation of job. Its kind of Divide And Conquer principle. And all the problems can be independent of memory. If they are independent you can use joblib.

Comment: Does anyone know why this function takes a lot of memory in my system?

Answer (score 0):

Verbose =2 will definitely throw some light. Also try playing around with the number of iterations to see the performance impact. The other factor is the number of categorical features which will bump up the dimensions of the matrix to be iterated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).